# Check condition and return name of column for which the condition is fulfilled

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a *dataframe* that looks like this:

```
df_start <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  b = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
  c = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  n = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

I want to test the condition if any of the columns from `df_start[,2:n]` (where n shows the last column of the dataframe) are equal to `df$a` then create two new columns out of which the first one returns 1 if the condition is TRUE and 0 if it is not, and the other gives the name of the column for which the condition was TRUE.

I managed to create the first column like this:

```
library(dplyr)

# check condition
df_start <- df_start %>% mutate(cond = ifelse(a == b | a == c | a == n, 1, 0))
```

Even though I think I need a different approach since I may have different number of columns every time. So I need to test the condition for column `a` and all columns from the 2 to the last one but I also would need to know for which column the condition was fulfilled.

Desired output:

```
# desired output
df_end <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                     b = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                     c = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     n = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                     cond = c(1,1,0,1,0),
                     col_name = c("c", "b", NA, "n", NA))
```

Is there a way to do this with `dplyr` maybe or base R ? Although any other solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`. I like to use `gather` and `spread` for such approaches.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_start %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k, v, -a, -rowname) %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  mutate(cond=ifelse(any(a==v), 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(col_name=ifelse(cond==1, k[v==1], NA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(k, v) %>% 
  select(-rowname)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
      a  cond col_name     b     c     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1 c            0     1     0
2     1     1 b            1     0     0
3     1     0 NA           0     0     0
4     1     1 n            0     0     1
5     1     0 NA           0     0     0
```

Or without transforming a piping/apply-solution like

```
df_start %>% 
  mutate(col_name=apply(.[-1], 1, function(x, y) y[x==1], colnames(.)[-1])) %>% 
  mutate(cond=as.numeric(apply(.[-ncol(.)], 1, function(x) any(x[1] == x[-1]))))
  a b c n col_name cond
1 1 0 1 0        c    1
2 1 1 0 0        b    1
3 1 0 0 0             0
4 1 0 0 1        n    1
5 1 0 0 0             0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution:

```
m <- df_start[,1] == df_start[,2:4]

df_start$cond <- rowSums(m)
df_start$col_name[!!rowSums(m)] <- names(df_start[2:4])[max.col(m) * rowSums(m)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df_start
>   a b c n cond col_name
> 1 1 0 1 0    1        c
> 2 1 1 0 0    1        b
> 3 1 0 0 0    0     <NA>
> 4 1 0 0 1    1        n
> 5 1 0 0 0    0     <NA>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The following uses base R only.
Note that in order to create column `cond` there is no need for `ifelse`.

```
df_end <- df_start
df_end$cond <- with(df_start, as.integer(a == b | a == c | a == n))
df_end$col_name <- NA
inx <- apply(df_start[-1] == df_start[[1]], 1, function(x) min(which(x)) + 1)
is.na(inx) <- is.infinite(inx)
df_end$col_name <- names(df_start)[inx]

df_end
#  a b c n cond col_name
#1 1 0 1 0    1        c
#2 1 1 0 0    1        b
#3 1 0 0 0    0     <NA>
#4 1 0 0 1    1        n
#5 1 0 0 0    0     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solution @Jimbou with tidyverse. For completion, you can arrange the outcome by changing the last line in Jimbous code with:

```
select(-c(rowname, cond, col_name), c(cond, col_name))
```